# How to display an activity indicator while loading in app purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have a button that calls the in app purchase feature. I would to display a loading wheel while it is loading the product and the dismiss it when the UIAlertView to confirm the purchase appears. I am using the MBAlertView to show other messages in my app and I would to use it also here. 
How can I do it? I want to display it when the user presses the button and dismiss it when it receives a response.

Here is my code at the moment!

```
- (IBAction)buyCoffeeInAppPurchase:(id)sender {
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                 initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:     @"com.giovannibalestra.emergencycall.Thankyoudeveloper"]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
    // I should add something like this line of code to show the activity indicator but I can only set hidesAfter some seconds
    // [MBHUDView hudWithBody:@"Wait." type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeActivityIndicator hidesAfter:4.0 show:YES];
}
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    NSLog(@"%@",[[myProduct objectAtIndex:0] productIdentifier]);

    SKPayment *newPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[myProduct objectAtIndex:0]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:newPayment];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Unsuccessful"
                                                        message:@"Your purchase failed. Please try again."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: SET `breakpoints` in each of the function in your `InAppPurchase` class  to know the flow of  `InApp`  and show/hide `MBAlertView` accordingly!

Comment: buyCoffeeInAppPurchase  ....--- >show    and   completeTransaction ----> hide ,failedTransaction --- > hide

Comment: hv u got the solution dude.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For show loading you can also use MBProgressHUD. Its a easy way to show loading process. Download MBProgressHUD.h & .m file from internet & just copy in xcode project.

`HOW TO USE:` Import this #import "MBProgressHUD.h" in your .h & .m files & also this MBProgressHUD *HUD; in .h file.
Then in .m file your code looks like:

```
- (IBAction)buyCoffeeInAppPurchase:(id)sender {

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) ];
       HUD.labelText = @"Fetching...";
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];
        [HUD show:YES];


    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                 initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:     @"com.giovannibalestra.emergencycall.Thankyoudeveloper"]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
    // I should add something like this line of code to show the activity indicator but I can only set hidesAfter some seconds
    // [MBHUDView hudWithBody:@"Wait." type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeActivityIndicator hidesAfter:4.0 show:YES];
}
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    NSLog(@"%@",[[myProduct objectAtIndex:0] productIdentifier]);

    SKPayment *newPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[myProduct objectAtIndex:0]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:newPayment];

    [HUD hide:YES];
    [HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Unsuccessful"
                                                        message:@"Your purchase failed. Please try again."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this one tonight. I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue 
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions 
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
        }
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
        }
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        }
        else {
            // Do something.
        }

        // You can dismiss your Activity Indicator (MBHUDView) here.
    }
}
```

Comment: this would dismiss the activity indicator even in the states SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing & SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred. Furthermore it doesn't handle parallel transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simply apply the activity indicator when user clicks on purchase button and stop the activity indicator after this method - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction. Don't forget to stop in failed transaction too, other wise activity indicator start animating. Some times activity indicator needs to calls through threads is they not visible. So please try that too.